# Is the map-getter an unnecessary entity?

Tags: html, css, sass

There is such `SCSS` code:

```
$font-weights: (
  "font-weight-thin": 100,
  "font-weight-light": 300,
  "font-weight-regular": 400,
  "font-weight-medium": 500,
  "font-weight-bold": 700,
  "font-weight-black": 900,
);

@function font-weight($font-weight-style){
 @return map-get($font-weights, $font-weight-style);
}
```

Then we can use it in the form of the following function call:

```
.header_top_navigation{
  font-weight: font-weight(font-weight-regular);
}
```

Question: 
What are the advantages (and what tasks does it solve) this approach in comparison with the use of ordinary `SCSS` variables?
Or is it just an equivalent but more cluttered alternative?

Comment: Seems like unnecessary overhead to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just extra code and it is error sensitive:

- You need to write a specific function for each map.
- When you change the name of your map you also need to change your function.

A valid reason to create a function might be that you don't like the syntax of the map-get and want to create a shorthand to make it a bit more readable. You could do this:

```
function mg($map, $key) {
  @return map-get($map, $key);
}
```

And you can use it like this for every map:

```
.header_top_navigation{
  font-weight: mg($font-weights, "font-weight-regular");
}
```